# How to combine human-labelled data with user behavior data?

Tags: deep-learning, supervised-learning

I am working on a supervised learning problem for a web-search task, where I have access to a relatively small set of human-labeled examples and lots of user-behavior data.

Now, user behavior data is biased, because of presentation bias, position bias etc. So it's likely that its' distribution will be different from human-labeled data.

I am planning to use both to train a Neural Network model.

Now I am confused about how to combine both datasets?

Comment: nice topic, thanks for asking about it; I am not sure about understanding the bias due to the user behaviour, can you give any more detail on it?

Comment: Thanks for responding. So the task is query classification into some predefined categories. From user clicked documents, can create a dataset, but it will be biased by documents on the top position, plus the mode of presentation etc.

Comment: Could you provide some samples and/or the structure of your data

Comment: I think you are looking for semi-supervised methods.

Comment: @PedroHenriqueMonforte . Sure. The data is for E-commerce. It looks like this: (query, product category, CTR(query, product category)). Human labelled data is simply (query, product category).

Comment: @EngrStudent I am not sure if it falls under the semi-supervised umbrella. We have two kinds of labelled data. One of them is human-labelled, the other one is derived from the click-log. In semi-supervised learning, you have lots of unlabelled data.

Comment: "product category" is the item a person was trying to get with a "query", is that it?

Comment: @SHASHANKGUPTA - the word "lots" is qualitative.  If you can characterise the label, then you can associate appropriately.  Over time that can adapt and make better.  One might consider it a version of using hand-labeling to bootstrap performant automated labeling.  It is your problem and you understand it best, so make the calls you need to make.

Answer (score 2):

That is a common scenario in a learning to rank problem. One heuristic is to separately model explicit (human-labeled) and implicit (user-behavior) features. Then combine the separate feature groups with a learned weight for their final relative contribution. [Improving Web Search Ranking by Incorporating User Behavior Information](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/improving-web-search-ranking-by-incorporating-user-behavior/) by Agichtein et al goes into greater detail.

[RankNet](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/blog/ranknet-a-ranking-retrospective/) takes this approach using a neural network.